# Banco de Dados criado com Core Data em Swift

Tags: banco-de-dados, ios, swift, xcode

preciso criar um app que é um formulário com dados básicos (nome, idade, email, etc) e que salve os dados para acesso depois, mas que além de salvar na tableView, crie o arquivo de banco de dados ou planilha. Vi que o CoreData e o Realm geravam um arquivo DB.

Podem me informar como acessar esse arquivo, ou como criá-lo, caso isso não seja feito automaticamente com a importação do CoreData no projeto?

Já possuo um app com CoreData implantado e que salva notas que escrevoe as lista em uma tablView, porém preciso alterá-las para um formulário e que gere esse arquivo em formato DB para fazer o backup dos dados.

Muito obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 0):

Então tanto o Realm quanto o CoreData criam um arquivo no diretório do App:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[AppID]/Documents/
```

Nesse diretório você consegue ter acesso ao **.db** do seu banco de dados.

Para ter acesso a esse diretório basta acessar pelo NSFileManager:

```
let documents = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

Isso irá retornar uma lista de diretórios, porém você precisa pegar só o primeiro, depois disso é só listar os arquivos e pegar aquele que você deseja.

Gosto muito de utilizar o CoreData porém sugiro você usar o Realm pela simplicidade e por ser rápido para trabalhar.

Caso você use o realm existe [essa lib](https://github.com/mikemac8888/MMRealmCloud) para fazer backup dele para o iCloud Drive.

Espero ter te ajudado =D

Comment: Ajudou demais Victor! Muito obrigado! Assim que eu tiver reputação suficiente, votarei na sua resposta! Mto obrigado mesmo!